# Canvas 2DPath Clip overlap pr

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to create one compound shape in canvas that masks all the content below it - i will be animating these paths so they will eventually intersect - the problem is, when they intersect, they are doing a reverse mask when the drawing overlaps. I just want one solid mask.

```
let region = new Path2D();
            
            // first line
            //ctx.transform(1,0,0,1,xShift,yShift);
            region.moveTo(wdth*(.093+p1x) + p1x, ((ht*0)));
            region.lineTo(wdth*(.096+p2x)  + p2x, ((ht*0)));
            region.lineTo(wdth*(.302+p2x)   + p1x, ((ht*1)));
            region.lineTo(wdth*(.299+p1x), ((ht*1)));
    ctx.save();
            //ctx.fill(region);

            //
            ctx.beginPath();
            region.moveTo(wdth*.326, ((ht*1)));
            region.lineTo(wdth*.329, ((ht*1)));
            region.lineTo(wdth*.537, ((ht*0)));
            region.lineTo(wdth*.534, ((ht*0)));
    ctx.save();
            //ctx.fill(region);
            //
    ctx.beginPath();
            region.moveTo(wdth*.680, ((ht*0)));
            region.lineTo(wdth*.683, ((ht*0)));
            region.lineTo(wdth*.464, ((ht*1)));
            region.lineTo(wdth*.461, ((ht*1)));
    ctx.save();
            //ctx.fill(region);
            //
    ctx.beginPath();
            region.moveTo(wdth*.926, ((ht*1)));
            region.lineTo(wdth*.929, ((ht*1)));
            region.lineTo(wdth*.702, ((ht*0)));
            region.lineTo(wdth*.699, ((ht*0)));
            ctx.fill(region);
            //ctx.beginPath();
            //
            ctx.clip(region, "nonzero");
```

Here is an example ( as you can see there is a thin line that overlaps that isn't clipping correctly - however the OTHER line DOES clip correctly ):

https://codepen.io/pdub888/pen/MWjrdwe

Comment: You are better off using a hidden canvas and drawing all your shapes normally, then doing on big mask on the final canvas using `globalCompositeOperation`. Probably more efficient and you can visually check your work in the debugger.

Comment: In the same vein/example, using globalCompositeOperation: 
https://codepen.io/pdub888/pen/vYXpwmv
Still that odd overlap issue.

Comment: Not like that, draw every path with the default operation (source-over), then draw that buffer canvas on top of your final canvas with say ‘destination-out’ (one of those, cant check atm) to mask your final canvas with the alpha of your buffer.

Comment: Same issue ( I think i'm doing what you're asking ) : 
https://codepen.io/pdub888/pen/ZEpvdGx

Comment: Check out my answer, I modified your snippet from codepen, and it does work if you don't draw it as a single path due to the winding algorithm (see also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/fill-rule)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is draw it in a separate - hidden - buffer canvas, just fill all the shapes - there's no need for a Path2D constructor unless you will reuse it, but even then you should not draw your entire shape like this (because of the winding algorithm, certain bits are not part of the fill, but thats not entirely relevant for masking images here - more info and examples here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/fill-rule)

Then use that buffer canvas to cut mask another canvas using a `globalCompositeOperation`. Below I have modified your snippet and removed the constructor, and acted directly on the buffer canvas.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
      let canvas = document.getElementById('mainmask');
      let gradcanvas = document.getElementById('gradmask');
            let aWrapper = document.querySelector('.canvas-wrap');
            let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      let ctxGrad = gradcanvas.getContext('2d');
            let win = {};
            let markerShow = false;

            // for reszing canvas 
            function setCanvasScalingFactor() {
               return window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
            }
            
            function resizeViaCanvas() {
                //Gets the devicePixelRatio
                var pixelRatio = setCanvasScalingFactor();
                //The viewport is in portrait mode, so var width should be based off viewport WIDTH
                if (window.innerHeight < window.innerWidth) {
                    //Makes the canvas 100% of the viewport width
                    var width = Math.round(1.0 * window.innerWidth);
                }
                //The viewport is in landscape mode, so var width should be based off viewport HEIGHT
                else {
                    //Makes the canvas 100% of the viewport height
                    var width = Math.round(1.0 * window.innerHeight);
                }
                //This is done in order to maintain the 1:1 aspect ratio, adjust as needed
                //var height = width*.5625;
                var height = Math.round(1.0 * window.innerHeight);
                //This will be used to downscale the canvas element when devicePixelRatio > 1
                aWrapper.style.width = width + "px";
                aWrapper.style.height = height + "px";
                canvas.width = width * pixelRatio;
                canvas.height = height * pixelRatio;
        gradcanvas.width = width * pixelRatio;
                gradcanvas.height = height * pixelRatio;
            }
            // two colors for mask gradient
            //let color1 = [201, 237, 223]
            let color1 = [5, 5, 5]
            let color2 = [226, 124, 99]
            
            // various rgb colors
            let mint = [201, 237, 223]
            let red = [239, 65, 35]
            let fadedred = [226, 124, 99]
            let purple = [28, 16, 42]
            let beige = [255, 236, 173]
            let peach = [251, 199, 143]

            
            let scaleAmt = 1;
            // where the mask is drawn based on tweening scaleAmt
            function drawMask() {
                //the length of each square
                var w = Math.round(canvas.width);
                var h = Math.round(canvas.height);
        console.log( w + "WIDTH" + h + "HEIGHT")
                ctxGrad.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                ctxGrad.save();
                // ctx.fillStyle = `rgba(239, 65, 35, ${viaAlpha.alpha})`;
                ctxGrad.fillStyle = `"rgb(" + color1[0] + "," + color1[1] + "," + color1[2] + ")"`
                //

                
                let wdth = w;
                let ht = h;
                let xShift = 0;
                let yShift = 0;
                
                let p1x = -.1;
                let p2x = .1;
        
        var gradient = ctxGrad.createLinearGradient(0, 0, w, 0);
                gradient.addColorStop(.4, "rgb(" + color1[0] + "," + color1[1] + "," + color1[2] + ")");
                gradient.addColorStop(1, "rgb(" + color2[0] + "," + color2[1] + "," + color2[2] + ")");
                ctxGrad.fillStyle = gradient;
                ctxGrad.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
        ctxGrad.save();
        
        
        ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.lineWidth = 0;
                ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
                // first line
                //ctx.transform(1,0,0,1,xShift,yShift);
                ctx.moveTo(wdth*(.093), ((ht*0)));
                ctx.lineTo(wdth*(.096), ((ht*0)));
                ctx.lineTo(wdth*(.302), ((ht*1)));
                ctx.lineTo(wdth*(.299), ((ht*1)));
        ctx.fill();
        //ctx.save();


                //
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(wdth*(.326+p1x), ((ht*1)));
                ctx.lineTo(wdth*(.329+p2x), ((ht*1)));
                ctx.lineTo(wdth*(.537+p2x), ((ht*0)));
                ctx.lineTo(wdth*(.534+p1x), ((ht*0)));
        ctx.fill();

                //
        ctx.beginPath();
        
                ctx.moveTo(wdth*.680, ((ht*0)));
                ctx.lineTo(wdth*.683, ((ht*0)));
                ctx.lineTo(wdth*.464, ((ht*1)));
                ctx.lineTo(wdth*.461, ((ht*1)));
        ctx.fill();


                //
        ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(wdth*.926, ((ht*1)));
                ctx.lineTo(wdth*.929, ((ht*1)));
                ctx.lineTo(wdth*.702, ((ht*0)));
                ctx.lineTo(wdth*.699, ((ht*0)));
                ctx.fill();

                //ctx.beginPath();
                //
                //ctx.clip(region, "nonzero");
                //ctx.clip();
        
        ctxGrad.globalCompositeOperation='destination-in';
        ctxGrad.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
                
                ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
                

                //ctx.restore();
            }

//window.addEventListener("resize", resizeViaCanvas, false);
resizeViaCanvas();
drawMask();
});
```

```css
.canvas-wrap{
        position:fixed;
        width:100vw;
        height:100vh;
        top:0;
        margin: 0 auto;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        top: 50%;
        pointer-events: none;
        opacity:1;
    border:1px solid blue;
    background:transparent;
}

#mainmask{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity:.1;
  position:absolute;
  display:none;
}

#gradmask{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background:green;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

        <div class="canvas-wrap">
       <canvas id="gradmask">
      </canvas>
            <canvas id="mainmask">
            </canvas>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Interesting. I'm going over my code in my latest codepen ( the one with the two canvas elements ) and it looks like you mostly just removed it from a 2DPath element, right? Well this does look to be working....now I get to custom animate all those points. Fun. Thank you for your help today.

Comment: Yes and no - the composite operation was also changed (play with that, mdn has a grrat cheatsheet here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) Also, don’t forget that you can use transforms to do most of the heavy lifting of animation! Sliding, squashing, rotating. And remember you can always use a buffer to draw into the next. It’s probably sbly the fastest way of using canvas.

Comment: Well I thought this was good to go - but is there an issue with calling the drawMask ( drawing both canvases and then drawing/masking with composite onto the main canvas ) with request animation frame? ( i.e. do i need to save something or clear something? ). It disappears after the first call ( comment out the composite and it 'works' or rather draws ): 

https://codepen.io/pdub888/pen/abmEevO

Comment: *nevermind: for anyone using this code in the future, be sure to RESET the globalComposite on the main canvas BACK to 'source-over' at the top of your operations - otherwise it will continue to write as the previous composite.